# MediaRecorder Beep

Tags: android, mediarecorder

When i run

```
MediaRecorder.start()
```

my phone makes a beep.

Is there any way to silence the beep?

Running on nexus one 2.3.3

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to shut off the sound MediaRecorder plays when the state changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804205/how-to-shut-off-the-sound-mediarecorder-plays-when-the-state-changes)

Comment: that didn't work for me either